# Need help regarding add to card fly animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

Is there any library available in android which fly image to specific area and then disappear it like most of the shopping apps where when user clicks on add to cart, the particular product flies to the cart(some sort of animation).

How to do this stuff

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Yes, there is this nice library [here](https://github.com/dkmeteor/CircleAnimation) which is what you are exactly looking for. I have personally used it and can assure you that it does its job perfectly.

Its very **light-weight and simple** to use too.

Add this dependency,

```
dependencies {
    compile( 'com.dk.animation.circle:library:0.1.0@aar')
}
```

And to run it, just do this,

```
new CircleAnimationUtil().attachActivity(MainActiviy.this).setTargetView(mTargetView).setDestView(mDestView).startAnimation();
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: hi there i am getting few errors in the library such as two way view

Comment: I didn't get any such errors using it. I am afraid that this is also not in the scope of this question. If this answer helped you, please do upvote and accept the answer.